# Complejidad del método removeAll

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una duda en cuanto a cual es la complejidad del método `removeAll` de la clase `ArrayList`. Creo que en el peor de los casos sería de `O(n)`, siendo `n` el número de elementos que hay en el `ArrayList`.

Pero cual sería el orden de complejidad en el caso promedio?

Comment: Mejor emplear el método `clear()`  , `removeAll` es `O(n^2)`

Comment: La complejidad es de : O(n) ya que utiliza un Iterator Espero te sirva Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código fuente de dicho método en la clase AbstractCollection:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<?> e = iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        if (c.contains(e.next())) {
            e.remove();
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

Lo cual removeAll tiene una complejidad de O(n^2)